# "no more data to read from socket" message when using with clause (in oracle sql developer)

Tags: oracle, with-clause

I am trying to simplify a select statement by using `with` clause in oracle sql. Below is the code; when I run it, first it opens a pop-up window saying "*Your database connection has been reset. Any pending transactions or session state has been lost*.".  Then it starts running but at the end it gives the message "*no more data to read from socket*".

I am able to run other queries (also using with clause) successfully. However, this one doesn't work. Can you help me solving the issue?

Thanks in advance.

```
WITH M AS
  (
  SELECT *
  FROM MASTER_REPORT_SOURCE_TABLE
  )
  ,
  POL_CUST AS
  (
  SELECT
    BRANCHCODE
    ,COUNT(POLID) NUMBER_OF_POLICIES
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT CUST_ID) NUMBER_OF_CUSTOMERS
  FROM M
  GROUP BY BRANCHCODE
  )
  ,
  E AS
  (
  SELECT
    BRANCHCODE
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT CUST_ID) CUST_EMAIL_EXIST
  FROM M
  WHERE CUST_EMAIL_EXIST = 1
  GROUP BY BRANCHCODE
  )
SELECT
  POL_CUST.BRANCHCODE
  ,POL_CUST.NUMBER_OF_POLICIES
  ,POL_CUST.NUMBER_OF_CUSTOMERS
  ,E.CUST_EMAIL_EXIST
FROM POL_CUST, E
WHERE POL_CUST.BRANCHCODE = E.BRANCHCODE
```

Comment: This question is for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/). It's likely that the server's alert log contains information about why your session died.

Comment: I closed this as a duplicate, the titles and error messages match.  Although the code is clearly different between the two questions the "generic advice" in my linked answer should apply equally well here.  If not, let me know and I'll reopen this question.